# var_dump returns NULL in json_decode

Tags: php, json

I have a variable in Laravel, which is an array, but when I pass it to another view, I can't do "count" or "foreach with it".

It has the following format:

```
[{
    "imp": 18,
    "cantidad": 2,
    "pre": 379.5,
    "id": 62,
    "preu": "345",
    "marca_id": 4,
    "nombre_item": "zapato",
    "nombre_marca": "marca1",
    "item_codigo": "1234-xxa",
    "nombre_unidad": "NIU"
}, {
    "imp": 18,
    "cantidad": 2,
    "pre": 136.400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625,
    "id": 64,
    "preu": "124",
    "marca_id": 4,
    "nombre_item": "farol",
    "nombre_marca": "marca1",
    "item_codigo": "3434-f",
    "nombre_unidad": "NIU"
}]
```

I tried:

```
$detalle = json_decode ($detalle, true);
var_dump($detalle);
```

But it returns null, I don't know what's going on.

---

EDIT:

EmailController.php (Here I send the variables of my view through ajax post, I send the variable $detalle that is an array of Eloquent de Laravel.)

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;

class EmailController extends Controller
{

    public function enviaremail(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);

        $data = array(
            'email' => $request->email,
            "numero" => $request->number,
            "nf" => $request->nf,
            "tienda" => $request->tienda,
            "total" => $request->total,
            "detalle" => $request->detalle,

            "fechae" => $request->fechae,
            "pdf" => $request->pdf
        );

        /* Mail::raw('Text', function ($message) use ($data) {
                $message->to($data['email']);
                $message->subject('Comprobante '.$data['nf'].'-'.$data['numero'].' Factura de '.$data['tienda']);
             $message->from('no-reply@mg.maks.uno', 'Maks.uno');

        }); */

        Mail::send('venta.email', $data, function ($message) use ($data)
        {
            $message->to($data['email']);
            $message->subject('Comprobante ' . $data['nf'] . '-' . $data['numero'] . ' Factura de ' . $data['tienda']);
            $message->from('no-reply@mg.maks.uno', 'Maks.uno');
        });

        return;

    }

}
```

Here is an excerpt from the view, which sends ajax the variables to EmailController.php

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ route('enviaremail') }}",
    data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "email": email,
        "numero": number,
        "nf": nf,
        "tienda": ti,
        "fechae": fe,
        "total": tt,
        "pdf": pdf,
        "detalle": "{{   $det  }}"
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert("Tu email fue enviado!")
    }
});
```

And it is in email.blade.php (the view that renders the EmailController.php variables) where I want to traverse the array or the other variables.

```
<?php
    var_dump(json_decode($detalle, true));
```

Comment: Where do you put the json in `$detalle` ?

Comment: Your code works. Could you please show the entire code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using "**html_entity_decode**"

```
$jsonText = $request->detalle;
$decodedText = html_entity_decode($jsonText);
$myArray2 = json_decode($decodedText, true);
```